# nextjs set process.env.baseUrl according to NODE_ENV

Tags: next.js

I am using `Nextjs`.

I want to set `process.env` by `NODE_ENV`

**packaged.json**

```
{
  ...
  "script": {
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && next",
    "prod" : "set NODE_ENV=production && next",
  },
  ...
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = withSass({
  ...
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "devServer" : "prodServer"
  }

})
```

and when I execute with `yarn dev`, I can see "prodServer",

How can I use it separately?